# program running infinite times if entered character sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: c

this is a menu driven program having two functions. everything works fine if i enter numbers but when i enter character it runs infinite times sometimes :( 
like when i enter integers it works fine and if i enter char it shows some junk value and then try again option is showed and i again enter char it runs infinite times

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void cal()  
{
int x,y,z;
printf("enter two numbers\n");
scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
z=x+y;
printf("%d\n",z);
}
void mul()
{ 
int x,y,z;
printf("enter two numbers\n");
scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
z=x*y;
printf("%d\n",z);
}
void main()
{
int x,c;  
clrscr();
menu :
printf("1.sum\n");
printf("2.mul\n");
printf("enter choice\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
switch(x) 
{ 
case 1:cal();break;
case 2:mul();break;
default :printf("try again\n"); 
}
printf("press 5 to run another function\n");
scanf("%d",&c);
if(c==5)   
{
goto menu;
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: using `%d` for character input is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Maybe instead of asking for ints you should ask for two arrays of chars and attend to convert them to ints, if that fails then you return an error.

Comment: @Dayalrai not UB. It remains not read the case.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for citation. Please let me know what's wrong with my first comment.

Comment: @Dayalrai It is not undefined behaviour If you enter a non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating your gcc compiler. I ran the code on gcc 4.8 and the code terminated well for characters as well. 
Otherwise if you really want to handle characters as well you take an input using a char pointer (string that is ) and then using atoi(str) store it in an int variable and then process it. And you can check :  if the user enters characters ( using isalpha() ) then terminate the code.

Sample Code : (ran well enough)

```
char *s = malloc(64);
scanf("%s",s);
if(isalpha(s[0]))
    return ;
else 
   int x = atoi(s);
   int sum = x + 1; //or whatever manipulations you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

"when i enter character it runs infinite times sometimes ..."

All the code that tries to read an `int` uses the following of some sort.  When non-numeric data is entered, `scanf("%d", ...` does not consume that IO (leaving it for the next IO operation), does not set `c` to any value, and then returns a 0 (which is not tested).  At that point `c` has whatever value it had before the `scanf()` call.  Since `c` was not initialized, its value could be anything - hence undefined behavior as suggested by @BLUEPIXY

```
int c;
...
scanf("%d",&c);
```

Since the non-numic data is left for the next IO and the next IO could be another `scanf("%d"`, code is stuck in a rut - infinite loop.

To best fix, initialize variables, get the user input via `fgets()` and detemrine the value via sscanf() or `strtol()`.

```
int c = 0;
char buf[80];
if (fget(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOerror();
if (sscanf(buf, "%d",&c) != 1) Handle_NonNumericInpupt();
```